# objective-c: NSJSONSerialization fail when data is from string

Tags: objective-c, nsjsonserialization

In my parser I have a method that give back the result object of a API. It fail when the content data is a string:

```
 ...
 resul = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

        return resul;
```

resul is nil.

But data is not nil: if execute :

```
NSString *strResul = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

strResul is "MY STRING".

Why NSJSONSerialization fail only in this case?

Comment: "MY STRING" is not valid json. You can test if your json is valid here… https://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0):

If the expected result can be `NSString` you have to pass `NSJSONReadingAllowFragments`

Answer (score 0):

The string should be in a valid JSON format in order to work 
Because  `NSJSONSerialization` will result in an `NSArray` or an `NSDictionary`

Comment: With the option [NSJSONReadingAllowFragments](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonreadingoptions/nsjsonreadingallowfragments?language=objc) `NSJSONSerialization` can also deserialize non-collection types.

Answer (score 0):

Your string's format is incorrect. The following string is correct

```
{
    "title": "Team member - sunnyxx",
    "content": "Working at Baidu, Zhidao iOS team, weibo: ",         
    "username": "sunnyxx",
    "time": "2015.04.11",
    "imageName": "sunnyxx"
}
```

or you initialize a dictionary and transfer it to jsonString, then use the api to parse it.